# Is there a way to get Docker daemon REST API calls?

Tags: macos, docker

I'm looking for a way to see the contents of the requests the Docker CLI makes to the Docker Daemon for image creation, container creation etc. Is this possible to see, and if so, how?

Comment: I believe you're looking for this. https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/

Comment: That's simply the documentation for using the REST API. I'm curious if there's a debug feature I'm not aware off that prints the contents of the requests the Docker CLI makes to the Daemon when a user inputs a command

Answer (score 1):

You can run the docker daemon with debugging enabled which will show the URL being requested, but not the contents of the request. In /etc/docker/daemon.json, you can configure debugging with:

```
{ "debug": true }
```

Then restart the service. On systemd based systems, you can see the logs with `journalctl -u docker`.

Comment: The log is available on the osx host from `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/log/docker.log`

Comment: @Matt that directory is actually empty for me for whatever reason

Comment: @sreya That's odd. Do you have anything in `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux`

Comment: Updated location directory location on **macOS**: `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/log/vm/`